# Azure Data Explorer - Kusto query: unauthorized error querying from an Azure AD application

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-data-explorer, kql

I would like to create a web application where to run ADX queries.
I followed the instruction here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/provision-azure-ad-app
to create and register the AAD application with ADX

Here the code

```
    var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(<ADX cluster uri/database>);
    kustoConnectionStringBuilder.WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(<ApplicationId>, <Application Secret>, <TenantID>);
    var kustoClient = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
    var query = "AdtPropertyEvents\r\n| count";
var reader = kustoClient.ExecuteQuery(query);
```

The ExecuteQuery call is giving an unauthorized error

[image: Unauthorized (401-Unauthorized)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the same document and I created an application with the necessary API permission **`user_impersonation`** to access azure data explorer and make sure to grant admin consent to your permission like below:

[image]

You need to create the database and add permission to your Application like below:

[image]

Once you have added you can follow this code to run the query using C#

**Code:**

```
using Kusto.Data;
using Kusto.Data.Net.Client;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Replace placeholders with actual values
        string clusterUri = "https://<clustername>.<location>.kusto.windows.net";
        string database = "your-database-name";
        string applicationId = "your-app-id";
        string applicationSecret = "your-app-secret";
        string tenantId = "your tenant id";

        var kcp = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(clusterUri, database).WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(applicationId, applicationSecret, tenantId);
        var kustoClient = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kcp);

        string query = "table1 | count";
        var reader =kustoClient.ExecuteQuery(query);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt64(0));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

The above code was executed and successfully returned the count of table1 in my database.

```
1000
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! My error was in the  new KustoConnectionStringBuilder call :  new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(<ADX cluster uri/database>);(<ADX cluster uri/database>); instead to have cluster URI and db as two different parameters, they were passed as a single string