# How to compose applicationClientId, applicationKey, or authority in KustoConnectionStringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, kql, azure-authentication

I am very new to Kusto, and I am able to connect Database using withuserpromtAuthentication. But I want to connect to Kusto using WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication.

I am not aware of applicationClientId, applicationKey, or authority w.r.t. my application. Can anyone give examples of how to compose these?

```
var appId = "<appId>";
var appKey = "<appKey>";
var appTenant = "<appTenant>";
//Create Kusto connection string with App Authentication
var kustoConnectionStringBuilderDM = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(ingestUri)
    .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(
        applicationClientId: appId,
        applicationKey: appKey,
        authority: appTenant
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To get values of applicationClientId, applicationKey and authority,
> you need to have **Azure AD application**.

I registered one Azure AD application in my tenant like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> New registration***

[image]

In the **Overview** of that application, you can find *applicationClientId* and *authority* values like this:

[image]

To get value of `applicationKey`, you need to create one **client secret** like below:

[image]

You can find the **value** of  `applicationKey` from below screenshot:

[image]

You can use these **values** in your code to connect to Kusto using WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication.

**Reference:**
[Azure Data Explorer - Kusto query: unauthorized error querying from an Azure AD application - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76116176/azure-data-explorer-kusto-query-unauthorized-error-querying-from-an-azure-ad/76117616#76117616)

Comment: I have follow your steps and I got Kusto.Data.Exceptions.KustoRequestDeniedException at ExecuteControlCommand

var adminProvider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslAdminProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder);
        var Query = ".ingest inline into table Rescue_Table <|\rTesting,200.12.1.0,osname,version";
        IDataReader dataReader = adminProvider.ExecuteControlCommand(Query);
Is it DB access issue?

Comment: Yes, RequestDenied is an access issue. Have you granted permissions or roles to that application as mentioned in the reference link?

Comment: 1) I have created ApplicationClientId,Authority and ApplicationKey in Azure portal
2) .add table TableName admins ('aadapp=ApplicationClientId')
3)Added API permission user_impersonation 

user_impersonation Admin consent by default No in azure portal and unable to change it Is it could be the reason as I am executing ingest query?

Comment: Yes, you need to grant admin consent to that `user_impersonation` permission.

Comment: ok, Thanks for your support ,Its really helpful to me. I need one more thing Do you know how to compose ApplicationToken?